# How to use jQuery hide boostrap4 Modal with Angular?

Tags: jquery, angular

I added jquery, boootstrap to the package. JQuery works fine, but modal function not work.

**ts & html**

```js
import $ from 'jquery';
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular 5';

  closeModal() {
    $("#exampleModal").modal('toggle');
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
      Launch demo modal
    </button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="closeModal()">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**ERROR**

```
TypeError: jquery_1.default(...).modal is not a function
```

**live demo**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jquery-modal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use jQuery in Typescript you have to do it like this.
The line has to be placed after all imports.

```
//import $ from 'jquery';

 declare var $:any;

 export class AppComponent {
   name = 'Angular 5';

   closeModal() {
     $("#exampleModal").modal('toggle');
   }
 }
```